# python: ctypes, does argtypes automatically call constructors?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have code that works but I don't know why it works.

```
str2payload = lib3.str2payload
str2payload.argtypes = [POINTER(mbuf_t), POINTER(c_char)]

# sbuf = ..
val = b"asdfasdfasdhfjkasgdfjasgdfhjasgdfjhasgdfjhasgdfgjh"
rmr_str2payload(sbuf, val)
```

And this works as expected. Here, val is just a bytes object in python. However, the function signature says it should be a `POINTER(c_char)`. So what is doing the magical conversion?

btw, the reason I'm using `POINTER(c_char)` is because it says to here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.argtypes):

> When a foreign function is called, each actual argument is passed to the from_param() class method of the items in the argtypes tuple, this method allows adapting the actual argument to an object that the foreign function accepts. For example, a c_char_p item in the argtypes tuple will convert a unicode string passed as argument into a byte string using ctypes conversion rules.
>
> New: It is now possible to put items in argtypes which are not ctypes types, but each item must have a from_param() method which returns a value usable as argument (integer, string, ctypes instance). This allows defining adapters that can adapt custom objects as function parameters.